# Characteristics of electromagnetic radiation

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, wavelength

Is it possible to change the wavelength of an electromagnetic wave without a change of medium?

Comment: Yes, it is called Doppler effect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect

Comment: Raman scattering? Second harmonic generation? Parametric mixing?

Comment: Under the circumstances of a source and a receiver which are at a given distance to each over there is no way to change the frequency of a stream of photons, Photons are indivisible units and once emitted they travel until they hit an receiver. This is true for vacuum.

Comment: What is parametric mining @JonCuster

Comment: Mixing, not mining. Using non-linear optics to 'mix' two lasers giving sum and difference beams. Similar to SHG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to change the wavelength of light by propogating it into
a different medium, of course.   It is also possible, in the case of a birefringent medium, to change the wavelength of light by propogating into the exact same medium, but in a different orientation of polarization.   It's harder, but still possible, to use Kerr effect or Pockels effect to alter the refractive index of a medium (but only by a small amount).
In none of these cases does the light frequency change, though that could be accomplished by the Doppler effect, reflecting the light from a moving mirror.

There is also the famous Pound-Rebka experiment in which the wavelength and frequency of light was observed to change in upward versus downward propogation.  See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound–Rebka_experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment)

Comment: Note also that electro- and acousto-optic modulators can change the frequency of a light beam via sum and difference frequency generation processes.